# Update To Profile Not Saving On Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I have updated the User profile so that they can now add a bio to their profile. This has all been setup using Devise.

Everything works fine locally but when uploaded to Heroku the updates I make aren't saving. If I go the user profile and try to update the bio field it comes up with the message "You updated your account successfully." However I go back to my account and the bio hasn't been updated.

Have looked through the Heroku logs but cant seem to see where the error is originating.

```
    heroku logs
2014-08-27T15:53:42.548525+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-27T15:54:22.190453+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
2014-08-27T15:54:22.351283+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (6.0ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:22.369810+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 169ms (Views: 159.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:53:42.548527+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-27T15:53:42.548524+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_edit_html_erb__1928983160583724081_70011601502660'
2014-08-27T15:53:42.548522+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:20:in `block in _app_views_devise_registrations_edit_html_erb__1928983160583724081_70011601502660'
2014-08-27T15:54:31.415029+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PUT "/users" for 88.150.202.202 at 2014-08-27 15:54:31 +0000
2014-08-27T15:54:31.550935+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:31.551733+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 133ms (Views: 8.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:31.418364+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
2014-08-27T15:54:31.418419+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TgCTObji/2GV1qfIk2RHwChFmgM0CUnoe685JPIX9Os=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Patrick's Chairs", "email"=>"patrick@frnsh.co.uk", "bio"=>"Established in 1990.", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
2014-08-27T15:54:31.423532+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  cached plan must not change result type
2014-08-27T15:54:31.423536+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1
2014-08-27T15:54:31.549502+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (6.2ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:31.551447+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-08-27T15:53:42.546526+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (5.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:53:42.548493+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-27T15:54:39.694397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=3df598cf-b036-454f-ac72-f82f4f061f1c fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=183ms status=302 bytes=1471
2014-08-27T15:54:43.781382+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/vendors/2/listings" for 88.150.202.202 at 2014-08-27 15:54:43 +0000
2014-08-27T15:54:39.922353+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2014-08-27T15:55:21.207841+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/edit" for 88.150.202.202 at 2014-08-27 15:55:21 +0000
2014-08-27T15:54:45.893146+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:45.894409+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 2017ms (Views: 2004.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:21.222538+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (7.9ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:21.224995+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:52.034601+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:52.035765+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1005ms (Views: 1000.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:15.124819+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=f69f0226-2b3e-4055-8715-ccb3d4fcf9e4 fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3369ms status=304 bytes=1300
2014-08-27T15:54:22.184559+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/edit" for 88.150.202.202 at 2014-08-27 15:54:22 +0000
2014-08-27T15:54:22.274881+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (63.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:22.351865+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:11.167151+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PUT "/users" for 88.150.202.202 at 2014-08-27 15:55:11 +0000
2014-08-27T15:55:11.365097+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 195ms (ActiveRecord: 12.9ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:11.763023+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2014-08-27T15:54:39.519920+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
2014-08-27T15:54:39.519965+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TgCTObji/2GV1qfIk2RHwChFmgM0CUnoe685JPIX9Os=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Patrick's Chairs", "email"=>"patrick@frnsh.co.uk", "bio"=>"Established in 1990.", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
2014-08-27T15:54:39.689254+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://frnsh.herokuapp.com/
2014-08-27T15:54:41.378964+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:21.210544+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
2014-08-27T15:55:21.224329+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:21.225475+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 11.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:41.382440+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1460ms (Views: 1450.4ms | ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:51.030299+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2014-08-27T15:54:51.030307+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"vendor_id"=>"2"}
2014-08-27T15:54:39.516642+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PUT "/users" for 88.150.202.202 at 2014-08-27 15:54:39 +0000
2014-08-27T15:54:39.689444+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 168ms (ActiveRecord: 10.7ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:54.768259+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/edit" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=e3dd3fa2-fa1b-40b3-9603-846755f41e17 fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=1137
2014-08-27T15:54:52.032715+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (998.0ms)
2014-08-27T15:54:52.035325+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:27.305893+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2014-08-27T15:56:11.945134+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_out" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=5cf03750-9e5c-4881-8fde-79c45aa79e16 fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=302 bytes=1282
2014-08-27T15:55:17.567881+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2014-08-27T15:55:11.760136+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 88.150.202.202 at 2014-08-27 15:55:11 +0000
2014-08-27T15:55:18.639706+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:15.099044+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3327.5ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:15.115501+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:15.111230+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:15.116236+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 3350ms (Views: 3335.1ms | ActiveRecord: 13.2ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:18.640676+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1071ms (Views: 1060.3ms | ActiveRecord: 5.4ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:12.392430+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2014-08-27T15:56:47.170713+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:14.001538+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:14.002454+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1610ms (Views: 1603.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:24.434839+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:24.509393+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1495ms (Views: 1486.5ms | ActiveRecord: 6.3ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:24.433386+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1415.5ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:24.508725+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (73.4ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:23.012166+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 88.150.202.202 at 2014-08-27 15:56:23 +0000
2014-08-27T15:56:28.366087+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:28.370378+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1058ms (Views: 1017.4ms | ActiveRecord: 25.7ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:31.819357+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
2014-08-27T15:56:31.833761+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:31.834471+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 8.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:47.169292+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1043.0ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:47.171690+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:47.171834+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1073ms (Views: 1049.7ms | ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:11.926879+00:00 app[web.1]: Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 88.150.202.202 at 2014-08-27 15:56:11 +0000
2014-08-27T15:56:11.929998+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
2014-08-27T15:56:11.930022+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"TgCTObji/2GV1qfIk2RHwChFmgM0CUnoe685JPIX9Os="}
2014-08-27T15:56:11.940178+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://frnsh.herokuapp.com/
2014-08-27T15:56:11.940333+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:23.014719+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2014-08-27T15:55:21.245141+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/edit" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=d0ff6ceb-b122-49a4-81fb-f19f47af5159 fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=59ms service=30ms status=304 bytes=1158
2014-08-27T15:55:18.646548+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/vendors/2/listings" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=2ee8b1f0-1e83-4ed4-9f79-db2d4ab09b20 fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=1086ms status=304 bytes=1299
2014-08-27T15:56:41.100700+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 88.150.202.202 at 2014-08-27 15:56:41 +0000
2014-08-27T15:56:49.537748+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
2014-08-27T15:56:49.557637+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2014-08-27T15:56:49.558682+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 12.4ms | ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
2014-08-27T15:55:54.720242+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/edit" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=52ceb1bb-5808-40b9-82fd-c9e4da7a0915 fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=94ms status=200 bytes=1150
2014-08-27T15:56:24.512579+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=bf7cbaeb-bfc8-459e-bfcd-ffe8e515d88d fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1504ms status=200 bytes=1160
2014-08-27T15:56:22.578880+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_in" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=a86a31c1-ab21-4eda-9f11-b6640bef0cfd fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=157ms status=302 bytes=1276
2014-08-27T15:56:28.376839+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/vendors/2/listings" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=0dc25dfa-5636-411b-8bd2-fbd4ae97cd6f fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1212ms status=200 bytes=1279
2014-08-27T15:56:49.560503+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/edit" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=13fb4e09-c563-406a-be6f-1a939c751ec9 fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=34ms status=304 bytes=1157
2014-08-27T15:56:42.639325+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=b3a53e92-c663-49b6-b168-6efad61db54c fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1543ms status=200 bytes=1300
2014-08-27T15:56:47.181104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/vendors/2/listings" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=272f6a86-ff34-4699-a364-fd9e26cfac38 fwd="88.150.202.202" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=1092ms status=304 bytes=1299
2014-08-27T16:01:15.323746+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frnsh.herokuapp.com request_id=cf38ec59-913e-4cfd-ade1-12ba96042879 fwd="50.163.139.118" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=842
2014-08-27T16:00:47.061078+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1511.9ms)
2014-08-27T16:00:47.065668+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-08-27T16:00:47.064197+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2014-08-27T16:00:47.066061+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1520ms (Views: 1501.9ms | ActiveRecord: 16.6ms)
```

User model (user.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

     if Rails.env.development?
        has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x200", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
     else
        has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x200", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg",
        :storage => :dropbox,
        :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
        :path => ":style/:id_:filename"
     end

    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   validates :name, presence: true

   has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :sales, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "seller_id"
   has_many :purchases, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "buyer_id" 

end
```

Comment: I would post your controller for this and possibly your validations as well because if you are validating things like to password but the password is not being updated this could cause it to fail and the controller handling might be wrong in this case.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky I have added the User model. But the controller is handled by Devise for the User. Does this help?

Comment: since you are validating the image but not submitting one on update I feel it might some how be silently failing on this but I cannot be sure and do not know much about devise controllers. Maybe try adding `, if: lambda{|u| u.image}` to your `:image` validation ? Like I said not really sure.